# How do you format moment.js from year to days from now

Tags: javascript, html, momentjs

this is my first time asking a question on Stack Overflow. I am trying to get the days elapsed since a specific date but it will only return in years. Here's my code here, any help would be appreciated.

Html

```
<body>
    </div>
    <span>
        <div class="text">Time elapsed since 2/27/2018<div class=".countdown" id="clock6"></div><br></div>
    </span>
</body>
```

Javascript

```
function displayTime() {

    var time6 = moment("20180227", "YYYYMMDD").fromNow();

    $('#clock6').html(time6);
    setTimeout(displayTime, 1000);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    displayTime();
});
```

Comment: Not tried momentjs but having quick glance over the docs, it appears that anything more than 320 days will appear as "years"

Answer (score 0):

Use diff instead -

```js
function displayTime() {
    var previousDate = moment("20180227", "YYYYMMDD");
    var today = moment();
    var diffInDays = today.diff(previousDate, 'days');
    $('#clock6').html(diffInDays + ' day(s)');
    setTimeout(displayTime, 1000);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    displayTime();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>    
    <span>
        <div class="text">Time elapsed since 2/27/2018<div class=".countdown" id="clock6"></div><br></div>
    </span>
</body>
```